# How can I make my Javascript code select all 'b' tags on a page instead of only the first one?

Tags: javascript

We have a very large website that is quite old and has a lot of 'b' tags. My boss wants to change them to 'strong' tags but this will require a lot of time to change manually so she was hoping we could change it with some code.

I had a nice bit of JQuery code that worked (intermittently), but I couldn't get it to work on the site as it uses JQuery 1.9.1 and cannot be upgraded.

I then found this piece of Javascript which does what I need but only works on the first 'b' tag on the page and all others stay as 'b' tags.  I don't know enough about Javascript selectors to change the firstChild selector.

```
<script>
  function replaceElement(source, newType) {
    // Create the document fragment
    const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    // Fill it with what's in the source element
    while (source.firstChild) {
      frag.appendChild(source.firstChild);
    }
    // Create the new element
    const newElem = document.createElement(newType);
    // Empty the document fragment into it
    newElem.appendChild(frag);
    // Replace the source element with the new element on the page
    source.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, source);
  }

  // Replace the <b> with a <div>
  replaceElement(document.querySelector('b'), 'strong');
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just edit the source code? Why do you want to manipulate the DOM?

Comment: `querySelector` returns the first instance, `querySelectorAll` returns all. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`.

Comment: @JeremyThille I would prefer that but it's not my decision. It's a huge website with hundreds of pages and probably thousands of bold tags to alter. My boss doesn't want to be wasting time going through and manually editing all of the source code.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('b')).forEach(e=>{
    replaceElement(e, 'strong');
});
```

But this is really a [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You **really** should do the change server side, for example by using some search/replace (learn to use your code editor). You're adding to the code debt here.

Note also that there's no obvious reason to prefer `strong` over `b` in HTML5.

Comment: This must be a duplicate but I find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName). It's more efficient than `querySelectorAll` because it doesn't have to parse selectors, and it describes better what you are really trying to do - get elements by tag name.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("b");
replaceElement(elements[0], "strong");
replaceElement(elements[1], "strong");
replaceElement(elements[2], "strong");
```

You can also iterate over this collection by using `Array.from()`.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off finding the source of the `<b>` tags and changing them there as Denys has mentioned.

Updating the DOM would have little benefit and would cause performance issues when there are many tags on a page.

Does this system use a CMS or database to store the content? I would look to use something like these 2 SQL queries to replace them across the site:

update content_table set content_column = replace(content_column, '<b>','<strong>');

update content_table set content_column = replace(content_column, '</b>','</strong>');